# How to read variables of array of child components (Angular)

Tags: angular

The result of reading the variables of child components is the variable type's default values. How do I retrieve the actual values of these variables?

Child Component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  public displayName: string = ""
  public description: string = "";
  public summary: string = "";
  public isPrimary: boolean = false;
  
  constructor() { }

  clickme() {
    console.log(this.getModel());
  }

  public getModel() : Model {
    return {displayName: this.displayName, 
      description: this.description, 
      summary: this.summary, 
      isPrimary: this.isPrimary} as Model
  }

  static convertComponentsToModels(components: ChildComponent[]) : Model[] {
    var models = []
    for (let c of components) {
      models.push(c.getModel())
    } 
    return models 
  }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  childComponents: Array<ChildComponent> = [];

  addChild() {
    this.childComponents.push(new ChildComponent());
  }

  clickme() { console.log(CreateUseCaseFormComponent.convertComponentsToModels(this.childComponents));
  }
}
```

Note, the values in the child components are 2-way binded to the HTML form. I also confirmed that the values are actually populated by calling the child's `clickme` function. However, these values are not shown once these methods are called in the parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). This builds an iterable of components that are **existing** in your template (the existing part is important). You could then transform this iterable to an array using `toArray()` and call `foreach(childComponent => ...)` or whatever on this array.

You would then be able get your variables values as they are public from this array.

Comment: You emphasized that these components must already exist. Will this solution be viable if new instances of the child component were pushed into the iterable (say, a button click that adds a new instance to the iterable)?

Comment: @Peabrain Yes, What I wanted you to undestang when saying thet the component exists is that it must not be child of a *ngIf. if that *ngIf condition isn't met, then your component simply doesn't exist. If you want to be able to get's its variables values but hide it, use the `[hidden]` directive.